# angularjs ng-class not working properly with bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This piece of code

```
    <div ng-class="{alert: true, alert-success: geocode.success, alert-danger: !geocode.success}">{{geocode.status}}</div>
```

got error

```
Syntax Error: Token '-' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].
```

But if I update the code to

```
    <div ng-class="{alert: true, green: geocode.success, red: !geocode.success}">{{geocode.status}}</div>
```

it works.

ng-class doesn't like css name with `-` like `alert-danger` `alert-success`?

THanks

Comment: imo may would be good changing your post title adding the really issue like ng-class not working properly with bootstrap dashed class or similar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must quote the class name if it contains dashes:

```
<div ng-class="{'alert': true, 'alert-success': geocode.success, 'alert-danger': !geocode.success}">{{geocode.status}}</div>
```

This is because ng-class takes JavaScript object as its value and the object's keys (or any JavaScript identifiers for that matter) must not contain dashes.